# Using Facebook API paging?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm new to Facebook API and I would like to get information on the friends the logged user has. At first I had default privileges configured so all I got was just the names.
Once I've requested for additional privileges, it gave me a 'paging' object... But I have no idea of what am I suppose to do with it.
For some reason I wasn't able to find anything useful with Google, so here I am.

Here is what I have so far:

**index.html**

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        FB.init({
            appId: '118236041675713',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });  
</script>
<fb:login-button perms="email,user_birthday" autologoutlink="true">
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
              FB.api("/me/friends", {fields: 'name,id,birthday'}, function(res) {
                 console.log(res);
              });
           }
        });
});
```

**SOLUTION:**
Additional info can be received from the next/previous properties.
Important note: For some reason the jQuery `$.get` does work. So I had to use `$.ajax`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
               if (response.authResponse) {
                  FB.api("/me/friends", {fields: 'name,id,birthday'}, function(res) {
                     var next = res.pages.next;
                     $.ajax({
                url: next,
                success: function(data) { alert(data) },
                dataType: 'html'
              });
               }
            });
    });
```

Comment: The paging object contains the query to make to retrieve the next and previous page of results for the query you just made (if there are any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paging object will have 2 properties.

paging.next - this contains the url to the graph call that will return the next page of results

paging.previous - same but for previous page in results

Comment: How should I call it, with a simple ajax request?

Comment: there are several way to call it depending on your app, but yes... ajax will work.

Comment: I see people mentioning server side scripts and shortening the urls so that you can use them with the regular js lib.

Comment: My app is pure client-side. Is the paging method the only way I have to receive information from Facebook? It seems like a really bad way to implement an API.

Comment: I've tried to use the `next` for the ajax request and got a Bad Request Error (400).
`$.post(response.paging.next, {},
            function(data) {
                console.log('PAGE: ', data);
        }, "json");`

Comment: yes you can also use limit, offset or until and since in your calls.  [See This Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/)

Comment: this is my next: `https://graph.facebook.com/522839538/friends?fields=name,id,location,birthday&access_token=AAABriPlDg8EBAImUfrZBWZAr8ZCHlBscrCAsmQBFweKxYDSkAJteMfML8z4jT0sneuzIuQJmrDKvH2b7GrARg9j0dxFkNwanptgMQ1IyAZDZD&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=100004534507341`
Why do I get a bad request? Maybe my setting are wrong?

Comment: wow.. so you are setting limit and offset to 5000.  Basically you are say give me 5000 friends starting at friend 5000 (# 5001-10,000)... ergo bad request.

Comment: Hmm weird. As you can see in my example and the comment with the ajax request for the next page, I didn't set those values. Am I missing something here?

Comment: do you look at the page link that @StéphaneBruckert shared as well?  It has examples of using JS and paging.

Comment: Just tried it. Still getting the same Bad Request. I've set the `offset: 0`, and `limit: 400` for 400 friends. Can you place have a look at the way I make the AJAX call, a couple comments back? Thank you.

Comment: my suggestion is that __after_id and offset don't match.  I wouldn't use after_id... just use limit and offset.

Comment: That's what I do. I've setup a small example online: http://duskcloud.com/_test/index.html